# Exporting an array to txt file

Tags: c++, arrays, ofstream

I have a code that receives 3 numbers from the user, then sorts them and prints out a sorted array.
I'm trying to export the sorted numbers into a .txt file but all I get is some random number like "342142464" in the txt file.
I fail to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
std::ofstream ofs("sorted_numbers.txt");
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //array declaration
    int arr[3];
    int n,i,j;
    int temp;

    //total numbers to read
    n = 3;

    //read 3 numbers
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter number ["<<i+1<<"] ";
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    //print input numbers
    cout<<"Unsorted Array numbers:"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
    cout<<endl;

    //sorting - ASCENDING ORDER
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {       
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]>arr[j])
            {
                temp  =arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    //print sorted array numbers
    cout<<"Sorted (Ascending Order) Array numbers:"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
    cout<<endl; 

    ofs << arr[i] << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `ofs` instead of `cout` like in the same way you printed the sorted array to the console.

Comment: Move `ofs << arr[i] << std::endl;` to inside the last `for` loop.

Comment: `ofs` is an `ostream`, and `cout` is an `ostream`. Just treat `ofs` like `cout` and you'll be golden.

Comment: You should also add the file open mode onto the `std::ofstream` constructor. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/

Comment: Also, the reason you get the junk value is because `i == 3` when you write to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

> but all I get is some random number like "342142464" in the txt file.

`ofs << arr[i] << std::endl;`

This is the only thing you are writing to your file, which is also a UB (undefined behaviour) because the value of `i` here is `n` (after exiting from the previous loop).

`arr[n]` is out of bounds and can be any garbage value, or your program may even terminate.

**Solution:**

Just like you printed your sorted array to the console using `cout`, do the same thing with `ofs`:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    ofs << arr[i] << '\t';
ofs << endl;
```

Or you can do this in that previous loop itself:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    cout << arr[i] << '\t';
    ofs << arr[i] << '\t';
}
cout << endl;
ofs << endl;
```